# Changing names in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I read all textfiles in the working directory into a list, and cut some columns

```
all.files <- list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")
data.list <- lapply(all.files, function(x)read.table(x, sep="\t"))
names(data.list) <- all.files
data.list <- lapply(data.list, function(x) x[,1:3])
```

I am ending up with a "list of 2"

```
> str(data.list)
List of 2
 $ 001.txt:'data.frame':    71330 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1: Factor w/ 71321 levels
  ..$ V2: Factor w/ 1382 levels
  ..$ V3: num [1:71330] 89.1 99.5 98.8 99.4 99.5 ...
 $ 002.txt:'data.frame':    98532 obs. of  3 variables
  ..$ V1: Factor w/ 98517 levels 
  ..$ V2: Factor w/ 1348 levels 
  ..$ V3: num [1:98532] 99.5 99 99.5 98.4 100 ...
```

I want to rename V1,V2,V3 according to

```
new.names<-c("query", "sbjct", "ident")
```

How is this possible with lapply?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try `setNames`

```
data.list <- lapply(data.list, setNames, new.names)
```