# Changing a Single Column Across Multiple Data Frames in a List

Tags: r, lapply

These questions:

[Changing Column Names in a List of Data Frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648513/changing-column-names-in-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r)

[Changing names in a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944851/changing-names-in-a-list-of-dataframes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Both have great solutions to changing column names, but the only column name I want to change is the first column. The data frames in my list only have the first column in common.

Here is a reproducible example of the issue that I'm having:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 11:15, B = 21:25)
ldf <- list(df1, df2)
ldf <- lapply(ldf, setNames, "State")
L
[[1]]
  State NA
1     1  1
2     2  2
3     3  3
4     4  4
5     5  5

[[2]]
  State NA
1    11 21
2    12 22
3    13 23
4    14 24
5    15 25
```

How do I specify a single column in lapply and leave the rest alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` like :

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) {names(x)[1] <- "State";x})

#[[1]]
#  State B
#1     1 1
#2     2 2
#3     3 3
#4     4 4
#5     5 5

#[[2]]
#  State  B
#1    11 21
#2    12 22
#3    13 23
#4    14 24
#5    15 25
```

Comment: Perfect, I really need to learn functions. I tried using ldf <- lapply(ldf, names[1], "State"), which didn't work for obvious reasons. I will accept this answer when the timer allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(ldf, ~ .x %>%
              rename_at(1, ~ "State"))
#[[1]]
#  State B
#1     1 1
#2     2 2
#3     3 3
#4     4 4
#5     5 5

#[[2]]
#  State  B
#1    11 21
#2    12 22
#3    13 23
#4    14 24
#5    15 25
```

Or with `select`

```
map(ldf, ~ .x %>%
             select(State = 1, everything()))
```

---

Or using `setnames` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
lapply(ldf, setnames, old = 1, new = 'State')
ldf
#[[1]]
#  State B
#1     1 1
#2     2 2
#3     3 3
#4     4 4
#5     5 5

#[[2]]
#  State  B
#1    11 21
#2    12 22
#3    13 23
#4    14 24
#5    15 25
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lapply(ldf, setNames, c("State", names(ldf[[1]][-1])))
```